# Check if user is activated before sending access token in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt

I have followed [this](https://medium.com/@nydiarra/secure-a-spring-boot-rest-api-with-json-web-token-reference-to-angular-integration-e57a25806c50) turotial for implementing Spring JWT authorization. On top of this, the application is sending activation emails during registration. After clicking on the attached URL, the user is marked as activated (column registration_confirmed is marked as true in the database).

When user wants to login, request is sent to /oauth/token service with these params: grant_type=password, username=user, password=pwd

How can I check if user is activated before generating access token as a respose?

So far i wasn't able to find a way to do this.

Comment: Spring Security check by default, just do proper mapping to the `enabled` property of the Spring Security user and you will get this out-of-the-box.

Comment: You can create a user class by implementing the [UserDetails](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) class. Here you can override the `isEnabled()` method in order to check whether the user is activated or not.